# XFCE Cursor themes not installing

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xfce

I'm having a little trouble installing any cursor themes. I extract the archives contents to `/usr/share/themes` but when I go to Menu>Settings>Mouse and touchpad>themes all I see is default.

Using Archlinux, XFCE.

Comment: After further inspection, i have added the cursor folder to both ~/.icons and /usr/share/icons as well as /usr/share/themes too. I still do not get the option to change my cursor, just the default setting still,

Answer (score 3):

Icon and cursor themes need to go to `~/.icons` or `${sysprefix}/share/icons`

Have a look [here](http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes#cursors_44_and_46)